# LibGit2Sharp: Failed to clone repository into network drive

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I would like to clone the repository into a network drive (Azure share file storage) in my application. I have successfully mounted the Azure share drive on my Windows pc and granted the required permissions. I am able to read and write files in the shared drive without any issues. However, when attempting to clone a repository using the libgit2sharp library, I encounter an exception stating "repository path not owned by current user." Interestingly, I can manually clone the repository into the share drive using the "git clone" command in the command prompt. Could you please provide guidance on resolving this issue? For reference, I am using version 0.27.2 of the libgit2sharp library.

Comment: The next solutions might solve your problem: [Git command returns fatal error about the repository being owned by someone else](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/git-command-returns-fatal-error-about-the-repository-being-owned-by-someone-else-1167744132.html)